# How to use WCF Service to implement Soap response

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, soap

I am new to the wcf services and soap. Kindly give me an example or demo how to generate a soap request and response using wcf services. I need to use VB.net for this.

Comment: Just see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no point in writing that again - there's **sooooo many** excellent resources out there!

- [MSDN WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF)
- [WCF Beginner's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf)
- [Writing your first WCF service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/first_WCF_Service.aspx)
- [WCF Simple Sample](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2007/04/20/wcf-simple-example.aspx)
- [Video: Create your first WCF service](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Service/)

Answer (score 0):

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222253/need-a-basic-example-of-wcf-and-some-free-e-books